# Exclude mounted folders from tar archive

Tags: linux, ubuntu, backup, tar

we want to backup our server and this seems to be pretty simple thing to do except one. Currently we use something like this:

tar cvpjf backup.tar.bz2 --exclude=/proc --exclude=/lost+found --exclude=/backup.tar.bz2 --exclude=/mnt --exclude=/sys /

Everything is fine, but we do not want to include mount points, as several ftp users has chrooted access to their homes with mounts like:

mount --bind /var/www/folder /home/user/html

Is the any way to exclude such folders from being backuped? I checked help for tar,but cannot find any option like this.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic; should go on unix.stackexchange.com.